# How does one go about calculating non-time ordered correlation functions in scalar field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I am aware that expressions for the time-ordered expectation values of field operators can be derived using Wick’s theorem. My question is, how would one go about finding the corresponding *non-time-ordered* Green’s function/correlation function?

For example, if I wanted to calculate (in free real scalar field theory) the integral expression for

$$
\langle{0}|\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_3)\phi(x_4)\phi(x_5)\phi(x_6)|{0}\rangle,
$$

is there any shortcut? Or would I have to painstakingly go through the mode expansion of the fields and expand out in terms of creation and annihilation operators? Such an expansion here would involve 64 terms.

Comment: These are also called Wightman functions. You can still use Wick's theorem but with Wightman propagators instead of time-ordered ones. This follows from the mode expansion, or from the fact that Wightman functions are related to time-ordered ones by analytic continuation.

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend any resources regarding this? Particularly the point about Wightman functions being related to time-ordered VEVs by analytic continuation. Most textbooks I’ve looked through say next to nothing about Wightman functions, and a search online mostly yields results about Wightman axioms, rather than a streamlined route to actually calculating the functions/distributions themselves.